# Tabs converted to spaces, but still getting IndentationError

Tags: python, class, indentation

I have made sure that every tab in my editor has been converted to four spaces. I am coding in Python 2.7. After adding one argument to several subclasses, suddenly I am getting an IndentationError.

Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XXXXXXX\Dropbox\RPG\game.py", line 1, in <module>
    from player import Player
  File "C:\Users\XXXXXXX\Dropbox\RPG\player.py", line 1, in <module>
    import items
  File "C:\Users\XXXXXXX\Dropbox\RPG\items.py", line 16
    self.weight = 1
                  ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level    
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Here is the original code:

```
import random

class Weapon:
    def __init__(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("Do not create raw Weapon objects.")

    def __str__(self):
        return "\n{}\n=====\n{}\nValue: {}\nDamage: {}\nWeight: {} lb.\n".format(self.name, self.description, self.value, self.damage, self.weight)

class Dagger(Weapon):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Dagger"
        self.description = ""
        self.value = 2
        self.damage = random.randint(1, 4)
        self.weight = 1

class Longsword(Weapon):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Longsword"
        self.description = ""
        self.value = 15
        self.damage = random.randint(1, 8)
        self.weight = 4

class Armor:
    def __init__(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("Do not create raw Armor objects.")

    def __str__(self):
        return "\n{}\n=====\n{}\nValue: {}\nArmor/Shield Bonus: {}\nWeight: {} lb.\n".format(self.name, self.description, self.value, self.armor_bonus, self.weight)

    def modify_player(self, player):
        if self in player.inventory():
            player.armor_bonus = player.armor_bonus + self.armor_bonus

class PaddedArmor(Armor):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Padded Armor"
        self.description = ""
        self.value = 5
        self.armor_bonus = 1
        self.weight = 10

class LeatherArmor(Armor):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Leather Armor"
        self.description = ""
        self.value = 10
        self.armor_bonus = 2
        self.weight = 15

class Consumable:
    def __init__(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("Do not create raw Consumable objects.")

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} (+{} HP)".format(self.name, self.healing_value)

class HealerKit(Consumable):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Healer's kit"
        self.healing_value = 50
        self.value = 50
        self.weight = 1

class Bread(Consumable):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Bread"
        self.healing_value = 10
        self.weight = 0.5

class Cheese(Consumable):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Cheese"
        self.healing_value = 8
        self.value = 1
        self.weight = 0.5
```

Comment: What if you copy/paste your code from the question to the script?

Comment: I just copy pasted your code and tried to run it, no errors reported. Please try to copy paste this code (which you have posted here) to you original code.

Comment: Your code has no Indentation errors. ( at least code posted here)

Comment: I ran it too and no exceptions

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I pasted over my original code with the code in my question and all is working now. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your editor is not inserting TAB chars for newly inserted text.
You may by cut-n-pasting TAB for elsewhere.

Editors often default to a TAB being 4 spaces, but python assumes a TAB
is 8 spaces (this is the long standing convention).

You should also look for features in your editor to show you the tabs visible.

If your editor cannot you might wish to look for a better one for programming.